# i want to edit the product type in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I was trying to achieve the functionality as shown in the photo. I only added the functions as I got them from a website but they were added to the product data shown in woo-commerce but I cant achieve this functionality.

[image: requirement]

Comment: Are you using any page builder or plugin like Visual Composer or else?

Comment: WPBakery Page builder

Comment: That is Visual Composer. Let me know what exact problem you are having with it? I made many addons with WooCommerce and WP Bakery

Comment: i want to add the most viewed category in the drop down menu and i can't seem to find from internet how i am new to all this kindly help me

Comment: You can add WooCommerce category dropdown or autocomplete in WPBakery. Or else you can add a option to show the Top Most Categories only. For the first case you need to choose the category by name, it can be multiple. And other one will show the top most cattegories as it have some predefined codes. I did it in many themes [ in Theme forest ] with VC Addon Plugins

Comment: can you help me in it if we can contact through any site please

Comment: You can try this : http://studio.0effortthemes.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/tristup-studio.png